# Use multiple wildcards in a path in batch file

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

First of all, there are **similar** questions on Stack OverFlow like:

- [Windows - Batch file ignoring multiple wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429701/windows-batch-file-ignoring-multiple-wildcards)
- [How to specify multiple wildcards in a folder directory in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838599/how-to-specify-multiple-wildcards-in-a-folder-directory-in-cmd)

However, my use-case is a bit specific (or let's say: I couldn't manage to solve my problem using the lessons learned from the previous forum entries - mind that I am a pure beginner with Batch files).

What I want to do is to grab a file from a certain path, which includes a few subfolders (which change their names) - and copy it to another path which has similar folder structure.

I am currently stuck at the point, that I don't know how to set multiple wildcards in the source path, as it consists of a few things changing. Example:

**File in Source:**

```
C:\20170621_Update2017SR1\Polarion_update\_backup-20170627-1602.05\polarion\plugins\com.polarion.alm.tracker_3.17.0\configuration\MyPolarion\page.xml
```

**Target Directory:**

```
C:\Polarion\polarion\plugins\com.polarion.alm.tracker_3.18.2\configuration\My Polarion
```

Basically only the parts with numbers can change, so I was trying the following:

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\Polarion\polarion\plugins\com.polarion.alm.tracker*") do set "com.polarion.alm.tracker=%%a"
for /D %%b in ("C:\*_Update*\Polarion_update\_backup-*\polarion\plugins\com.polarion.alm.tracker*") do set "folder=%%b"

echo %com.polarion.alm.tracker% 
echo %folder%

set source="%folder%\configuration\MyPolarion\page.xml"
set destination="%com.polarion.alm.tracker%\configuration\My Polarion"
xcopy /s /Y %source% %destination%
```

I am pretty sure line 2 of my Code contains mistakes - because I don't know if I can set multiple wildcards like this.

The console gives me for line 2:

```
Echo is on
```

I don't understand what it means and what should I do.

Comment: `Echo is on` means that your batch file is trying to perform `echo` without anything after it. So that means that `%com.polarion.alm.tracker%` is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much Pieter!

Comment: You can't use wildcards in the folder path.

Comment: Hmmm, well line 1 and 4 kinda works for me.

Comment: Wildcards can only be used in the very last element of a path (I guess that's what @Squashman was actually referring to); so `D:\some_dir\*_name` works, but `D:\some_*\dir_name` doesn't. So every directory level with wildcards need to be resolved individually: `for /D %J in ("D:\some_*") do for /D %I in ("%~J\*_name") do echo Resolved two directory levels: "%~I"` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I already mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761805/use-multiple-wildcards-in-a-path-in-batch-file#comment94378982_53761805), wildcards can only be used in the very last element of a path (independent on whether this is a file or directory). That is why your command line containing `C:\*_Update*\Polarion_update\...` fails. However, you can resolve every directory level with wildcards individually, like this:

```
set "folder="
for /D %%b in ("C:\*_Update*") do (
    for /D %%c in ("%%~b\Polarion_update\_backup-*") do (
        for /D %%d in ("%%~c\polarion\plugins\com.polarion.alm.tracker*") do (
            set "folder=%%~d"
        )
    )
)
echo "%folder%"
```

If there are more than one matching directories on any levels, replace `set "folder=%%~d"` by `echo "%%~d"` to view them all.